Weakly convergent sequence in $L^2$
Let $(b_n(t))_n$ be a sequence of functions in $L^2(0,T)$ that converge weakly to a function $b(t)$ in $L^2(0,T)$.
I'm totally clueless in proving the following statement:
$$
\liminf_{n}b_n(t)\leq b(t)\leq \limsup_{n}b_n(t)\qquad \text{almost everywhere.}
$$
Any hint and suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

We can reduce to the case $b=0$ by considering $\tilde{b}_n=b_n-b.$ I think it suffices to apply $\int\limits_A\tilde{b}n(t),dt\to 0$ for any measurable $A\subset [0,T].$ For instance let $$A\delta={t,:, \liminf \tilde{b}_n(t)\le -\delta}$$ for $\delta>0.$

@RyszardSzwarc not sure how to pass to the limit with the pointwise limsup under the integral. The limsup might not be integrable. Can you detail your proof?

@RyszardSzwarc
Could you expand your comment into a complete answer? For example I don't understand why the integral of $\tilde{b}_n$ for any measurable A contained in $[0,T]$. Thank you.

By considering $b_n-b$ we may reduce to the case that $b_n\to 0,$ weakly.
Assume by contradiction that
the set $$\{t\,:\, \liminf b_n(t)>0\}$$ has positive measure. Therefore there is $\delta>0$ such that the set $$\{t\,:\, \liminf b_n(t)>\delta\}$$ has positive measure. We have
$$\{t\,:\, \liminf b_n(t)>\delta\}\subset \bigcup_{N\ge 1}\{t\,:\, \inf_{n\ge N} b_n(t)>\delta\}$$
Hence there is $N$ such that the set
$$A:=\{t\,:\, \inf_{n\ge N} b_n(t)>\delta\}$$
has positive measure.
By the weak convergence we have
$$\int\limits_Ab_n(t)\,dt=\int\limits_0^Tb_n(t){\bf 1}_A(t)\,dt\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$ However for $n\ge N$ we have
$$\int\limits_Ab_n(t)\,dt\ge \delta\,\mu(A)>0 $$ a contradiction.
The property $\limsup b_n(t)\ge 0$ almost everywhere follows from the observation that $-b_n\to 0$ weakly and $$\limsup b_n(t)=-\liminf(-b_n(t))$$ By the first part $\liminf (-b_n(t))\le 0$ a.e., hence $\limsup b_n(t)\ge 0$ a.e.
Remark The same proof is valid for $L^p(0,T),$ $1\le p<\infty.$ For $p=\infty$ it suffices that $b_n$ is convergent $*$-weakly. Note that for $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ the spaces are not reflexive.

For all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, the set
$$
B_N := \{ v \in L^2(0,T) \;\mid\; \inf_{n \ge N} b_n \le v \le \sup_{n \ge N} b_n \} 
$$
is closed and convex, thus sequentially weakly closed. Consequently, we get
$$
\inf_{n \ge N} b_n \le b \le \sup_{n \ge N} b_n
$$
for all $N$. Passing to the limit $N \to \infty$ yields the desired inequality.
